# How do I find out why I am getting the blue screen of freeze (not death)

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, freeze

I get a blue screen with "**Just a moment**" and a circular animation in two places.  It lasts about 10 minutes and then windows carries on as normal. Except that all file explorer windows are absent.  Every other program continues as if nothing had happened.

1. The first time I login after a reboot.
2. Randomly while I am using the PC, always in the middle of my typing something in any application, 2 to 3 times a day.

I have

1. Looked at the event log, but there are no errors around that time.
2. Tested cpu and memory - all good
3. Purchased another set of memory modules and swapped them in different patterns
4. Checked and repaired filesystem many many times.  Sometime it finds something to fix. But it doesn't stop the problem.
5. Looked at the registry for saved views `HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count`. Its value is 5000.
6. I increased the max count to 50K, but no luck.
7. I wrote a little program to reset this value every hour, no luck.

It is possible that its the saved views that is causing it.  But it is physically impossible for me to generate 5000 views several times a day (never mind 50,000).

The question is - **how can I find what might be wrong ?**

[image: Just a moment]

My system information is

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name RG2
System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model    H370M-D3H
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  Default string
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500 CPU @ 3.00GHz, 3000 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. F13, 5/06/2019
SMBIOS Version  3.1
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Product   H370M D3H-CF
BaseBoard Version   x.x
Platform Role   Desktop
Secure Boot State   Off
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\windows
System Directory    C:\windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale  New Zealand
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.19041.1806"
User Name   RG2\Rohit
Time Zone   New Zealand Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 48.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   46.9 GB
Available Physical Memory   32.2 GB
Total Virtual Memory    114 GB
Available Virtual Memory    98.5 GB
Page File Space 67.4 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, Disabled by policy
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

Comment: Microsoft modernized the BSOD with Windows 8, "just a moment..." actually is an indication your system has "crashed" (i..e BSOD) but even more so failed to display the error code in the process.  Does this behavior happen in a minimal boot configuration?

Comment: No, nor does it happen if I create another user and log in.  I recall, many years ago, that the pagesize space on drive C had to be large enough for a memory dump, or you got the BSOD with no error info.  But the page file is definitely bigger than the total memory.

Comment: I am suggesting that Windows is literally running into a problem, as it's attempting to generate the memory dump; you don't indicate what happens after the 10 minutes. I can only assume your system restarts.

Comment: No, it continues as normal.

Comment: Just edited my post to add - that all programs carry on except file explorer windows disappear.  Which is why I was looking at file save count.

Comment: "all file explorer windows" - What actions do you take at this point?  Do you manually restart File Explorer?  Your file save count is a wild herring.

Comment: I start the file explorer sessions s I need them.  But it does lose any settings such as view options  I think it goes back to defaults for them.

Comment: You shouldn't be losing your view options when File Explorer is restarted.   You will have to continue to diagnose the problem before any theories can be concluded.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS on your machine?